# i have an issue with user photo Trying to get property 'avatar' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

> Trying to get property 'avatar' of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Admin\resources\views\inc\header.blade.php) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Admin\resources\views\inc\header.blade.php) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Admin\resources\views\inc\header.blade.php)

i dont use a controller on this page, so i dont really know what to do

```
 <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
```

**Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('avatar')->default('default.jpg');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Model**

```
    use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;


    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{   
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
}
```

the error comes out when theres `{{ Auth::user()->'...' }}` comes out

```
        Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,
```

i expect theres something wrong in the middleware or a controller couse there is no problem before i implement my web with (User Permission) function

Comment: i cant really find a compatible answer for my problem, i hope anyone here can help me..

Comment: can we se your migration? and the user model?

Comment: use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

   
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{   
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
}

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('avatar')->default('default.jpg');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: you should edit your post and put this piece of code.

Comment: which code do you mean?

Comment: The migration and the model!

Comment: can you give me an example for this?

Comment: or put it in the answer section

Comment: I think you don't understand what i mean, you posted the migration and the user model in the comments session, you should'nt do that, you should put this on your question. Click on the edit button.

Comment: oh im sorry its my first time here

Comment: no problem, make sure you read the how to ask thread https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is my migration and the model of my user